# HttpsURLConnection and Charset for InputStreamReader?

Tags: java, character-encoding, httpurlconnection, inputstreamreader

In the code below:

```
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");

InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(input, "utf-8");
BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(reader);
...
```

An `InputStreamReader` is constructed with `UTF-8` because of `setRequestProperty` of `HttpsURLConnection`. However, I think the code really needs to get the `CharSet` from the response. But it seems like a chicken-and-the-egg problem.

Is it possible to retrieve the `CharSet` the server actually used in its response (instead of setting it to what I {wished|hoped} for)?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the best you can do is set the `Accept-Charset` request header to indicate the character encodings your client accepts. For example,

```
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
```

If the HTTP server is properly configured, the response will be UTF-8. The response `Content-Type` should contain the response's character encoding.

Comment: Thanks @Sotirios. I think that's what I am doing with `setRequestProperty`. And a misconfigured server is what I am concerned with. Its why I'd like to know what the server actually responded with so I can create the proper `InputStreamReader`.

Comment: @jww You're using `setRequestProperty` but setting the wrong header. Check the response headers and the body to verify the content-type.